# Add strings to array PHP

Tags: php, arrays, string

Hello I have $string1, Array[] and $string2. I want to create a Arraynew[] such that

```
Arraynew[0]=$string1
Arraynew[1]=Array[0]
.
.
.
Arraynew[n-1]=Array[n]
Arraynew[n]=$string2
```

The problem being that I don't know how many elements are in Array[] since it's from parsed data that changes and also I don't know how to formulate the above correctly in PHP.

Please help me.

Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`array_unshift()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-unshift.php) will insert one or more elements at the beginning of the array. [`array_push()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-push.php) will add one or more elements to the end of the array. So:

```
$new_array = $array;
array_unshift($new_array, $string1);
array_push($new_array, $string2);
```

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the excellent answer from cletus here are a couple of more ways:

```
$new_array = array($string1, $string2);
array_splice($new_array, 1, 0, $array);

// Or

$new_array = array_merge((array) $string1, $array, (array) $string2);
```

Comment: Thanks for the tips, I tried to use the array_merge function before creating the question, nice to see how to do it now.